# Django MaxLengthValidator default error message to string

Tags: python, django

`validator = MaxLengthValidator(32)`

I'm trying to return the error message for a `<MaxLengthValidadtor>` object. My hope is that there is a nice default message such as `'Field length must be less than 32 characters'` in which case I would return `validator.message` (this seems to be the case for custom validators).

However, `validator.message` returns an object `<django.utils.functional.lazy.<locals>.__proxy__ object at 0x7f8c78ef9320>` that contains empty strings in methods such as `validator.message.title()`.

Am I missing something or do I need to write out a custom message?

Comment: look at the source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/_modules/django/core/validators/#MaxValueValidator It does have a nice descriptive validation message

Comment: @karthikr yes, thank you. Is there a specific way to call that message. I would think that `validator.message` would return the message value. I'm sure I'm missing something basic. thanks

Comment: No, the way validators work are - they are applied on forms, and when validation fails, it shows the message on the field automatically.

Comment: @karthikr, understood. I'm trying to send it back to the client in JSON so need a string. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this in a view; here is how i get the errors in a json format:

```
if form.is_valid():
   # do valid things
else:
   return HttpResponse('{"result": "error", "formError": %s}' % json.dumps(dict(form.errors.items())), content_type='application/json')
```